# How to display the boundary of a text area

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've drawn a rectangle with rounded corners and I want to use it as a text box. But if I choose `area type` tool and click the rectangle, the rectangle will disappear. I can't set the `stroke` because it's for the texts themselves. So how to display the text box? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 2 rectangles. Area text boxes are not shapes intended to be visible.

Simply copy the first rectangle, proceed to add your text, when done `Edit > Paste In Front` and give the pasted rectangle the stroke.

Another option is to use an additional fill in the Appearance Panel with the *`Convert to Shape`* effect applied to create a rounded rectangle.

[image: rounded]

If you merely want a stroke and not a fill.. add a new stroke via the Appearance Panel rather than a fill, then apply the Rounded Rectangle Effect to the stroke.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your solution correctly. I created a text box, typed something, convert the selection (the text box) into a shape, then the text disappeared.

Comment: You're question states "I've drawn a rectangle with rounded corners...." Simply copy that rectangle before converting it to an Area Text box.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! One more question if you don't mind: I've given the rectangle and the text area the same radius of the rounded corner, but they don't seem to be matched. See http://imgur.com/kBMobRU

Comment: Area Text boxes can not have rounded corners. That question doesn't make sense to me. Do you perhaps mean you've created a **shape to constrain text within**? Constrained text is not area text. They are different.

Comment: I mean, in my attached link, the "gggg" should have been within the rectangle with rounded corners.

Comment: Use the second method I outlined above, with the Appearance Panel. It will be far easier to control.

Comment: It doesn't really work, the characters still go outside the bounding rectangle.

Comment: Start over. As you can see in my sample image above, it should work. You've got something odd taking place and without access to the file all I can do is guess. By starting over and using the second method I posted above, you should be fine.